# Covering N line segments with unit disks

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computational-geometry

Given a set of N disjoint horizontal line segments (parallel to the X-axis) of variable length and variable perpendicular distances in between, we need to place minimum numbers of unit disks that intersects at least one line segment or a unit disk such that the union of line segments and disks is connected. Is there any existing algorithm or anything I can use to solve this?

Comment: Well, this is a special case of Hitting Set, so you could formulate and solve it as that, but that's an NP-hard problem.  It's possible that a faster (even poly-time) algorithm exists that better exploits the properties of your problem (e.g., that if a disk hits intersects a line at y1 from x11 to x12 > x11 and another line at y2 > y1 from x21 to x22 > x21, then it necessarily also hits all lines containing any point inside the square (max(x11, x21), y1, min(x12, x22), y2))).

Comment: Can you please explain the solution more? Also it would be helpful if  an optimal or (1+ e) approximate solution for this can be obtained.

Comment: I'm afraid such a guarantee of approximation quality is outside my area of expertise.  The hitting set formulation is obvious; if you want to incorporate the observation about lines that may be hit, it's easy to do so in a branch-and-bound algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Finding an optimal solution is possibly NP-hard, as @j_random_hacker says. But perhaps a greedy algorithm produces a reasonable approximation.

Sort your segments by their left endpoints, and process the segments in that order, left-to-right. At any stage, you have a connected set of segments and disks to the left of the current not-yet-incorporated segment *s*. Find the closest object (segment or disk) to the left endpoint of *s*. Suppose this distance is *d*. Then connect *s* by a sequence of ceiling(d/2) disks along the line realizing that minimum distance *d*. *s* is now incorporated, and you can move on to the next segment.

One could easily create examples where this performs poorly, but there is quite a bit of room to improve via heuristics.

Comment: It would be helpful if an optimal or (1+ e) approximate solution for this can be obtained. Can you suggest how I can improve the greedy technique.

Comment: (1+eps) might still be challenging, for this is a cover problem, and in many versions only crude approximations are available. E.g., in "Covering Points by Unit Disks of Fixed Location' [PDF download}(https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/26b5/aa92a34231094d2090f10219d24d8410f58a.pdf), a 4-approximation is achieved..